# Ubuntu Lucid Redmine and SVN, can't access SVN via http://www.domain.com/svn

Tags: svn, ubuntu, redmine

Hi i've just followed all the steps
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstallUbuntuLucid#Automate-Repository-Creation

Got redmine working with the automation of repository. (basically i don't know how it works, is it suppose to create a repo whenever i create a project on redmine?)

However i cant seem to get www.domain.com/svn working. I can't access the repo from public.
It keep prompt me for password.

/etc/apache2/conf.d/svn.config

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine

    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "/var/svn" 
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy any

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine Subversion Repository" 

    #read-only access    
    
        Require valid-user
        Allow from [my server ip]
        # Allow from another-ip
         Satisfy any
    
        # write access
        
        Require valid-user
    

    ## for mysql
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost" 
    RedmineDbUser "redmine" 
    RedmineDbPass "password"
```

i tried adding these lines

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd into svn.config
```

and did  a and
sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd test.user
and set a password, however after restart , it stills the same even with user and password...

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Can't manage to get a satisfactory answer so... i've replaced with

```
 PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
Location /svn-redmine --> instead of /svn
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "/var/svn" 
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy any

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine Subversion Repository" 

    #read-only access    

        Require valid-user
        Allow from [my server ip]
        # Allow from another-ip
         Satisfy any

        # write access

        Require valid-user


    ## for mysql
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=localhost" 
    RedmineDbUser "redmine" 
    RedmineDbPass "password"
```

and created another vhost under sites-available/svn with

```
   ServerName www.xxx.com

  Location /svn
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /var/svn
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Public Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd"
     Require valid-user
  /Location
```

And that work for me